# Evolution of mass and velocity distributions under newtonian gravitation

Tags: newtonian-gravity

Let $\rho(r,t)$ and $v(r,t)$ be mass and velocity distributions. Given $\rho(r,0)$ and $v(r,0)$ (initial conditions) what is the differential equation that describes the evolution of $\rho(r,t)$ and $v(r,t)$ in space and time, assuming Newtonian gravitation?

You may assume $r$ to be one dimensional, if it makes writing the equations convenient.

**EDIT**

I think $v(r,t)$ should be replaced with $p(r,t) = \rho(r,t)v(r,t)$ and name it as momentum distribution to avoid some technical faults.

**EDIT 2**

It seems that to completely characterize an inviscid fluid flow, Euler equations are
needed.

The law of conservation of mass is already given in the answer. A component of pressure
is missing in the equation related to conservation of momentum.(first equation). Lastly a
third equation corresponding to law of conservation of energy should be introduced.(3rd
one of the euler equations of inviscid fluid flow).For the third equation we assume that
the internal energy per unit volume of the fluid is zero.

Comment: Is this question too basic to be asked here ?

Comment: @Marek: what is your take on this ?

Comment: well... most of your questions are answered in basic physics courses. Personally, I'd suggest you take some books (classical mechanics, continuum mechanics, quantum mechanics, maybe some mathematics for that, e.g. vector calculus) and study yourself and only ask for physical explanations of mathematics you don't understand. If this is what you're already doing then I think your questions are fine. Although maybe it wouldn't hurt if you provided some motivation as to why are you learning this stuff. Context always helps to provide better answers.

Comment: The reason why i am assuming internal energy of the fluid to be zero is not to venture into any other field, also as there is no intention to explain any physical situation as yet....physicists have been doing this for a long time now. Even if the model cannot sustain, we would atleast know what are the drawbacks of such a model completely. If we try to explain a physical situation directly, in most of the cases we run into trouble very soon and introduce theories on ad-hoc basis and what would happen is we will not be able to distinguish between a theory and physical reality !

Comment: Suddenly this question seems to be very interesting to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newton's law of gravitation says that to get the acceleration at a given point, you take any distant bit of mass and make a vector pointing towards it with length proportional to the mass and inversely proportional to the square of the distance to it.  Integrate that expression over the entire mass distribution.

$\frac{\partial{\vec{v}}(\vec{r},t)}{\partial t} + [\vec{v}(\vec{r},t)\cdot\nabla]\vec{v}(\vec{r},t) = G \int_{\textrm{space}}\frac{\rho(\vec{r'},t)}{|(\vec{r'}-\vec{r})|^3}(\vec{r'}-\vec{r}) \textrm{d}V(\vec{r'})$

$G$ is [Newton's gravitational constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant), and $\textrm{d}V(\vec{r'})$ is a volume element at the location $\vec{r'}$.

Alternatively, in terms of $\vec{p}$,

$\frac{\textrm{d}\vec{p}}{\textrm{d}t} = G\rho\int_{\textrm{space}}\frac{\rho'}{|\vec{r'}-\vec{r}|^3}(\vec{r'}-\vec{r}) \textrm{d}V(\vec{r}')$

Conservation of mass requires that the net flow of mass into a region of space result in an increase in the density there.

$\frac{\partial\rho(\vec{r},t)}{\partial t} = \nabla \cdot \vec{p}(\vec{r},t)$

Comment: To clarify, this is basically making use of Gauss's law for gravity.

Comment: It's just good old F=ma with F given by Newton's gravitational law.

Comment: @Mark Eichenlaub: request you to kindly edit the answer keeping in line with the new 'EDIT' part in the question.

Comment: @Rajesh  Sure.  The continuity equation looks better in terms of $p$.  However, the equation for the acceleration is easier to parse in terms of $v$ and makes more physical sense to me that way, so I'll leave that one as is.

Comment: @Rajesh added second-law equation in terms of $p$

Comment: @Mark Eichenlaub : what is $\rho^\prime$

Comment: @Rajesh I think they do match.  When I check the units I get length*time^-2 on both sides.  Are you counting the units of $G$?  $G$ has units of length^3*mass^-1*time^-2.

Comment: @Rajesh $\rho' = \rho(\vec{r}',t)$

Comment: @Mark Eichenlaub : sorry it was mistake. Is it possible to avoid the volume integral in any way.

Comment: @Rajesh You could integrate a scalar quantity to get a gravitational potential, thus avoiding integrating a vector quantity over a volume.  Then you'd take the gradient of the potential to get the acceleration.  But if there's mass everywhere, and you want to account for all of it, you're going to integrate.  If there is a lot of symmetry (like, for example, a spherically-symmetric mass distribution), then the volume integral might be very easy, but in general no, you cannot avoid it.

Comment: @Mark Eichenlaub : $(\vec{r'}-\vec{r}) \textrm{d}\vec{r}'$ What type of vector product is this ?

Comment: @Rajesh It's not a vector product.  $\vec{r}'-\vec{r}$ is a vector pointing from $\vec{r}$ to $\vec{r}'$.  $\textrm{d}\vec{r'}$ is a volume element located at the position $\vec{r'}$.  For example, in rectangular coordinates $x,y,z$ you would integrate over all $x,y,z$. $\vec{r}'$ becomes $x'\hat{x} + y'\hat{y} + z'\hat{z}$, with $\hat{x}$ a unit vector in the $x$ direction, etc. $\textrm{d}\vec{r'}$ becomes $\textrm{d}x\textrm{d}y\textrm{d}z$ in this coordinate system.

Comment: @Mark Eichenlaub : $ G \int_{\textrm{space}}\frac{\rho(\vec{r'},t)}{|(\vec{r'}-\vec{r})|^3}(\vec{r'}-\vec{r}) \textrm{d}\vec{r'}$ does not have dimensionality of acceleration. There could be something wrong with it !

Comment: @Rajesh  What dimensions do you think it has?  It looks like acceleration to me.

Comment: @Mark Eichenlaub : got it. I guess it is better to avoid $\textrm{d}\vec{r'}$ and use something else, it is very deceptive and confusing to have a vector notation for a volume element.

Comment: @Rajesh Okay, I see your point and it's updated.  But note that the notation $\textrm{d}\vec{r}'$ was not "deceptive" since it was explicitly stated to be a volume element from the beginning.

Comment: I think the first equation would be clearer (or at least a little more easily parseable) if you put parentheses or brackets in the second term, like $[\vec{v}(\vec{r},t)\cdot\nabla]\vec{v}(\vec{r},t)$.

Comment: @David I'll do that.  I guess you can actually interpret the expression either way, though.  $\vec{v}(\vec{r},t)\cdot[\nabla\vec{v}(\vec{r},t)]$ has the same meaning.

Comment: @Mark: true, I suppose, although in the notation I'm most familiar with (and which I think is most common), $\nabla$ only acts on a scalar field, whereas the directional derivative $\vec{v}\cdot\nabla$ can act on anything.

Comment: @David:  That is exactly right, since $\vec v \cdot \vec \nabla$ is unambiguous (the dot product acts on the index associated with $\nabla$), while it is unlcear whether $\vec v \cdot \left(\vec \nabla \vec w\right)$ means $v^{a}\nabla_{a}w^{b}$ or $g^{ab}v^{c}\nabla_{a}w_{c}$

Answer (score 1):

This problem is insoluble (since it is not well-posed) without a matter equation of state (and, unless you assume $T\approx 0$, a thermal equation of state).  If you specify a non-dust equation of state, it ends up having the Navier-Stokes equations embedded in it.  What do you need this for?  The above answers discuss some special cases (most specifically, static distributions) well, but this is still an open problem in the general case.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer: In Navier-Stokes equation if i assume the fluid is nonviscuous, i can get rid of one term.I  can also assume that the only bodily forces acting are due to gravity and convert $F$ to be solely due to gravity. Now the equation reduces to the equation given in the above answer.

Comment: You still need a relationship between the pressure (and temperature, if not at absolute zero) and the density, and if the fluid is not at absolute zero, you need a relationship between the internal energy of the fluid and the fluid's temperature.  We don't even have an existence and uniqueness theorem for the Navier-Stokes equations, much less the Navier-Stokes equations coupled to gravity

Comment: And sure, you can assume that there is no pressure (the bodily forces only being due to gravity), but that's still a choice of an equation of state (namely, the dust equation of state), and should be stated explicitly in the statement of the problem.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer: discarding thermodynamic nature of matter i do not understand why we need a relation between $\rho$ and pressure $P$ ? The only force here is due to gravity and we have considered that.

Comment: But the Pressure provides a force.  As the density changes, the force due to the pressure will change.  Unless you know how the pressure depends on the density, you have no control over how this takes place.  Think about solving either of Mark's equations--either equation involves an unknown $\rho$ and another unknown--either $\vec v$ or $\vec p$.  Either one is insoluble without another equation, since you need an equal number of equations and unknowns.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer: I could read that the gradient of pressure term is arising due to stress tensor.If we assume no stresses in the fluid, we can get rid of the gradient of pressure term and the Navier-stokes equation is reduced to the form given in the current answer.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer: My intention is to study the nature of newtonian gravity. I am not interested in describing any physical situation.Also the stress, viscuocity and other bodily forces are not arising purely from within the concept of newtonian gravity.

Comment: Of course, pressure is a term in the stress tensor.  So is density.  The matter in the solution has to obey some sort of equation of state.  If you don't specify that, you can't solve the initial value boundary problem, because the system will be underdetermined.  You can say that your equation of state is 'zero pressure', but you should say that in the initial formulation of your problem, rather than leave it to commenters to suss it out for them, and then tell them that they're not understanding your problem.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer: For an incompressible and non viscuous fluid, (which is nothing but a non zero mass distribution), Do you mean to say that even though the very origin of pressure is due to the gravitational force but the initial pressure $P(r,t=0)$ should be given as an independent quantity as $\rho(r,t=0)$ and $p(r,t=0)$. Please clarify the concept to me.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer: I am not sure whether i was correct in my previous comment. What i am puzzled about is that what is the need for pressure, when its very origin is due to gravitational force itself.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer: I think the pressure can be expressed in terms of Gravitational field strength $F$ and $\rho$. My question is whether to include such a term in the equation as gradient of pressure on the right hand side of the equation

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer: i didn't read your earlier comment about requirement of another equation relating $\rho$ and pressure $P$ for to be able to solve. But we have the conservation of mass equation and hence we can solve the equations without any need for a new equation relating $\rho$ and pressure $P$.

Comment: You need another equation for them, because the relationship between the density and pressure is different for different materials.  Also, an incompressible fluid is an approximation that doesn't work very well for relativistic fluids (and very definitely has nonzero pressure anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Gauss law of gravity is what you want [wikipeadia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27_law_for_gravity). This will give you $\vec{g}$ at each location.