# Behaviour of mass and momentum distributions under Newtonian Gravity

Tags: newtonian-gravity

In the context of this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1428/a-question-on-evolution-of-mass-and-velocity-distributions-rhor-t-and-v) should mass distribution $\rho(r,t)$ and momentum distribution $p(r,t)$ be well behaved ? By 'well behaved' it is meant that derivatives of all orders exist everywhere.

I don't see any reason why they should be well behaved. For the equations (given in the answer (by Mark Eichenlaub) to the above mentioned question) to be consistent the conditions required are

1. $\vec{p}$ should be continuously differentiable in order that $\nabla\cdot\vec{p}$ exists.
2. $\rho(r,t)$ should be partially differentiable wrt $t$ i.e., $\frac{\partial\rho(\vec{r},t)}{\partial t}$ exists.

   Please give strong reasons as to why it is required that $\rho(r,t)$ and $\vec{p}(r,t)$ to be always well behaved ?

Comment: Are you stating that the distributions should be well behaved, or asking whether they should? Because I don't think they necessarily are, at least not if you allow point particles.

Comment: @David Zaslavsky : I am asking whether they should be ? what are the consequences if they are not well behaved ?

Comment: @David Zaslavsky : Apart from satisfying the two conditions If they are not well behaved then why would it lead to existence of point masses ?

Comment: Consider editing your question to end the first sentence with a question mark, then. Also, I mentioned point particles as an example of a mass distribution that would not be well-behaved (or _smooth_, to use the technical term).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will $\rho$ always behave well? No, not at all.

This is physics, not mathematics -- if something is wrong with solutions, the explanation is simple: too bad for equations, probably approximations behind them lack some process or the mathematical description starts to be invalid.

In your case, it is obvious that a cloud with no angular momentum will be collapsing into one point, yet this is not a problem -- it is just "physical" that there will be some repulsion that would start to be significant in high density regions invalidating this simplified model.

Comment: @mbq: the intention here is not to explain any physical reality. Its just a question.

Comment: @mbq: It is not necessary that a cloud collapsing into a point implies that $\rho(r,t)$ is not well behaved.

Comment: @mbq: existence of repulsion in high density regions is something outside the current theory.

Comment: What on earth do you mean by 'well behaved' if a discontinuous, non-differentiable function is 'well-behaved'?  Because a point mass's density distribution is neither differentiable nor continuous.  It will also have time derivatives that discontinuously vanish at the point at which it coalesces to a point mass.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer : It keeps on reducing, that is what you mean by a point mass i suppose.The radius of the cloud becomes smaller than any arbitrary small $\epsilon$ provided we wait for sufficiently long duration. It never indeed becomes zero. There is no reason why an arbitrarily small cloud (mass distribution) shouldn't be well behaved.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer : here by radius i mean the support of the function $\rho$

Comment: No.  It is predicted to reach zero in a finite amount of time in both Newtonian and Relativity theory, unless there is a pressure that can stop the collapse.  If you have access to it, look up "Oppenheimer-Snyder collapse" in Misner, Thorne and Wheeler's 'Gravitation'.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer : For a counter example consider $\rho = \eta_\epsilon$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. Here $\eta_\epsilon$ is a  bump function. Bump functions are smooth and have compact support.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer : Consider the situation in this question, the equations are so clean and neat that i am pretty sure it would'nt go to zero in finite amount of time.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer : i mean the equations in the link given in the current question.

Comment: If you give that bump function a dust equation of state, after a finite amount of time, it will evolve into a point mass.  It will start as a well behaved continuous function and end up a as an ill-behaved one.  That is my whole point.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer : by introducing a dust equation of state (i precisely don't know what it is, i guess it is introduced to explain certain physical phenomenon) we are moving away from the scope of the question, and the current theory of newtonian gravitation.The newtonian grvitation does not exactly predict the existence of a dust equation of state. It is not inside the theory.

Comment: @Rajesh Your problem is that there is no physical system that just fully follows those equations (they don't form any "newtonian gravitation theory" -- NG is only $Gm_1m_2/r^2$). Physicist talk about reality, not  models on their own -- that's why you are still getting answers jumping beyond your model.

Comment: you need a relationship between the density and pressure of the fluid to solve the problem.  A dust equation of state simply states that the pressure is always zero, so that the problem is easily solveable.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer: Why can't i use euler's third equation (conservation of energy) so that the equations becomes solveable ?

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer : I actually am trying to solve by considering the euler equations but it is becoming to complicated. I don't know the reason why ?

Answer (score 1):

They are not necessary well behaved. But if they're not you will use distributions instead of functions. For example, if $\rho$ is not continuous, $\partial\rho/\partial t$ will behave like a Dirac distribution. The maths are just more complex, rarely bring new insight about the physics, that's why physicists often assume the functions to be regular enough.

Comment: Apart from satisfying the two conditions mentioned should they behave well ? this is the question i intended to ask.